# How to Align Paragraph in Center using OpenXml C# for PPT?

Tags: c#, xml, alignment, powerpoint, openxml

I'm trying to align my paragraph in the center for ppt but its not working!

This is my code:

```
 public static void ChangeSlidePart(SlidePart slidePart1,PresentationPart presentationPart)
    {
        Slide slide1 = slidePart1.Slide;

        CommonSlideData commonSlideData1 = slide1.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();

        ShapeTree shapeTree1 = commonSlideData1.GetFirstChild<ShapeTree>();

        Shape shape1 = shapeTree1.GetFirstChild<Shape>();

        TextBody textBody1 = shape1.GetFirstChild<TextBody>();

        D.Paragraph paragraph1 = textBody1.GetFirstChild<D.Paragraph>();


        D.Run run1 = paragraph1.GetFirstChild<D.Run>();


        run1.RunProperties= new D.RunProperties() {FontSize = 6600};

        run1.RunProperties.Append(new D.LatinFont() { Typeface = "Arial Black" });


        //run1.Append(runProperties1);
        D.Text text1 = run1.GetFirstChild<D.Text>();
        text1.Text = "Good day";
        
    }
```

I tried adding to this paragraph properties with the corresponding justification but nothing was updated.

Comment: Is code returning the paragraph you are trying to modify?  You are using FIRST a lot in the code and maybe on the first item is getting updated in stead of the entire paragraph.

Comment: Actually im new to openXml and i have to do this task in a short time.. I saw that this was able to change the thing i wanted to the "Good day" text but i dont know where i should place the alignment thing and how because i tried a lot and its not working. @jdweng

Comment: OpenXml is a text file so opening in Notepad may help you figure out where the change belong.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that easy to do this using Open XML SDK. With [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/), you can align a paragraph as shown below:

```cs
// The presentation variable here is an instance of the Presentation class.
var firstShape = (IAutoShape) presentation.Slides[0].Shapes[0];
var firstParagraph = firstShape.TextFrame.Paragraphs[0];
firstParagraph.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = TextAlignment.Center;
```

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for .NET](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/net/). This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to align a paragraph using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```cs
var slidesApi = new SlidesApi("my_client_id", "my_client_key");

var filePath = "example.pptx";
var slideIndex = 1;
var shapeIndex = 1;
var paragraphIndex = 1;

var paragraph = slidesApi.GetParagraph(
    filePath, slideIndex, shapeIndex, paragraphIndex);

paragraph.Alignment = Paragraph.AlignmentEnum.Center;

slidesApi.UpdateParagraph(
    filePath, slideIndex, shapeIndex, paragraphIndex, paragraph);
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.